# Update table based on condition in parent table

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables defined in my database:

```
moderator (id, name)

parent_object (id, moderator_id, parent_name)

child_object (id, parent_id, child_name, quantity)
```

I want to update a child object based on the ID. I currently have something like this which works:

```
update child_object set child_name = "Fred", quantity=5 where id = 3;
```

However, there is a security hole because this allows any moderator to update any child object that they do not own. If the moderator_id is 2, how can I do the update on this table so that it will only update if the moderator_id of the parent_object is 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql `update` you can do joins.

```
update
  child_object c
  join parent_object p on p.id = c.parent_id
set
  c.child_name = "Fred",
  c.quantity = 5   -- Seriously, this better not be a string.
where
  c.id = 3 and p.moderator_id = 2
```

Comment: Thank you. That works great. And yeah, I actually did not have quantity in real table. I was attempting to simplify it to post here and didn't pay attention to whether it should be numeric or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
update child_object set child_name = "Fred", quantity="5" 
where id = 3 AND parent_id IN (Select id from parent_object where moderator_id = 2)
```

This should work, but using "IN" is expensive.
Alternatively, you write a test query first to validate the the update is allowed.

```
Select parent_id, moderator_id FROM child_object c
Left Join parent_object p on p.id = c.parent_id
```

Comment: Using `in` to get a single row isn't more expensive than running the queries separately.  Correlated subqueries can start to get expensive in some cases, but that's when you get there you just have to optimize well.